# Unable to read from database records sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is the first time that I am using sqlite3 and that I'm working with databases. I'm making an online tic tac toe game, so that I can play with my friends. In `def dataRead():` I'm trying to read the data that the user has entered from the registration window and I'm trying to check if the data has already been saved in the database. If yes, the user has to enter another username.

```
    def register():
        ##initialising sqlite
        con = sqlite3.connect("userData.db")
        c = con.cursor()
        def submit():
            #creating tables in the database
            def createTable():
                c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userInfo(username TEXT, password TEXT)")

            def dataRead():
                username = user.get()
                password = pword.get()
                c.execute("SELECT username FROM userInfo")
                data = c.fetchall()
                try:
                    for row in data:
                        if row == username:
                            Label(regWin, text = "Sorry, username already in use...\nTry another one.", fg = "red").pack()
                            print(data)
                        else:
                            dataEntry(username, password)
                except TypeError:
                    dataEntry(username, password)
                    
            def dataEntry(username, password):
                c.execute("INSERT INTO userInfo(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
                con.commit()
                
            createTable()
            dataRead()
```

I tried using `c.fetchall()` to read the records for `username` in `userInfo`, so that the program can check if the username is available or not, but it doesn't seem to work (for me at least).

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Is it returning the wrong data? Is if throwing an error, and if so, what is the error" Is the function not being called at all?

Comment: it simply doesn't return anything, nor does it write in the database

Comment: Have you verified whether the functions are even being called when you expect them to be called? What have you done to debug this?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating multiple instances of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, create once instance of `Tk` and then create other windows as instances of `Toplevel`. You should also call `mainloop` only once.

Comment: yeah all of the functions are being called. I spent like 30 mins trying to debug it. I use the idle and I tried to look answers on the internet for my issue.

Comment: @BryanOakley but tkinter is not the issue

Comment: Then why is there tkinter code in your example? If this is purely a sqlite question, remove all of the tkinter code.

Comment: `data` will be a tuple of data from database inside a list, so you need to go inside the list first and then loop through, so try something like `data[0]` instead or something. Best way to find is open an IDLE and connect with the database and then `print(data[0])` and find which one exactly you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The records returned are tuples, so you need to use `row[0] == username` instead:

```
def dataRead():
    username = user.get()
    password = pword.get()
    
    c.execute("SELECT username FROM userInfo")
    data = c.fetchall()
    found = False
    for row in data:
        if row[0] == username:
            found = True
            Label(regWin, text = "Sorry, username already in use...\nTry another one.", fg = "red").pack()
            print(row)
            break
    if not found:
        dataEntry(username, password)
```

---

However, you don't need to fetch all records from the database.  You can use `WHERE` clause to get the required record:

```
def dataRead():
    username = user.get()
    password = pword.get()

    c.execute('SELECT username FROM userInfo WHERE username = ?', (username,))
    data = c.fetchone()
    if data:
        Label(regWin, text = "Sorry, username already in use...\nTry another one.", fg = "red").pack()
        print(data)
    else:
        dataEntry(username, password)
```

---

Also it is better to make `username` field an unique field:

```
def createTable():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userInfo(username TEXT PRIMARY KEY, password TEXT)")
```

So that no duplicate username in the table.

Answer (score 3):

The ***fetchall*** method returns a list of tuples, whether one column is selected or many. Therefore the comparison here `if row == username:` will never be true. If you want the first element of the tuple it is the usual, ie `row[0]`.

Comment: so what shall it be?

Comment: @shmifful as i mentioned, `data[0]` should be fine i guess. or even change your query

Comment: yeah, the query only works with data[0]. what should i change it to?

Comment: quick doubt `'SELECT username FROM userInfo'`,did you mean the `username` over here to be `username = user.get()`. if so, then this is wrong way to do so

Comment: @shmifful `row`  is a tuple from the list `data`. `username` is the first element of the tuple, addressed as `row[0]`.

Comment: you meant `fetchall()` please make the changes